# Mysql workbench connection to database fails due to plugin 'caching_sha2_password'

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I need to connect to a wordpress database and I don't want to install phpmyadmin because I am using windows and don't want to install php, neither apache so I decided to use mysql Workbench, I entered the hostname, username and password of the database but got the error `Failed to Connect to MySql at database_host:port Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' reported error: Authentication requires secure connection`  I saw this is due to the authentication method, so the databse is using an old one and mysqlworkbench since the 8.0 version use the sha2 method I also saw that I can use this `ALTER USER 'yourusername'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'youpassword';` to use the mysql_native_password method but won't this affect all my connections? How can I connect to this wordpress database using the native_password method witout altering the others connectins?

Comment: If you use flush privileges will have an impact.
It is recommended to create a separate user and grant permissions